# How to change content of a QML combobox when the index of another comboBox changes?

Tags: javascript, qt, combobox, qml

Basically If I have a comboBox that has two values. If I choose the first, the second comboBox content changes into ["60"]. If it's the second index, then the second comboBox's values changes back to ["20","30","60"] which is the originally initialised content of the comboBox.

```
 ComboBox
                  {
                      id: keyTypeComboBox
                      anchors.centerIn: parent
                      height: parent.height*0.8
                      width: parent.width*0.9
                      model: ["choice 1", "choice 2"]

                      onCurrentIndexChanged: changeContent();
                  }





 function changeContent()
    {
        if(ComboBox1.currentIndex == 0){
            ComboBox 2 change to ---->["60"]
        }else{
            ComboBox 2 change to ----> ["20","30","60"]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this by binding `currentIndex` property from the first one combobox with the `model` property in the second one combobox:

```
ComboBox {
    id: combo1
    model: ["choice 1", "choice 2"]
}

ComboBox {
    id: combo2
    model: combo1.currentIndex === 0 ? ["60"] : ["20","30","60"]
}
```

Function's usage is not necessary here.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I posted my own solution when I figured out what I was doing wrong as well.

But your answer seems much cleaner so I'll choose it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized what I was doing wrong.

it was the syntax. It should be:

```
if(ComboBox1.currentIndex == 0){
        ComboBox2.model = ["insert data"]
    }else{
        ComboBox2.model = ["insert other data"]
    }
```